# Drum machine plays the same sound

Tags: reactjs, audio

My drum machine plays the same sounds regardless of the button pressed, all the links are different, when I looked at the `console.log` output it shows that `this.audio` is the last url in my keys object. Can someone explain why?

```
const keys = [{
  name: 'Q',
  url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3',
  description: 'Heater-4_1',
  },{
  name: 'W',
  url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3',
  description: 'Heater-1',
  },{
    name: 'E',
  url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3',
  description: 'Kick_n_Hat',
  },{
    name: 'A',
  url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/punchy_kick_1.mp3',
  description: 'Chord_1',
  },{
    name: 'S',
  url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Chord_1.mp3',
  description: 'punchy_kick_1',
  },{
    name: 'D',
  url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Brk_Snr.mp3',
  description: 'Brk_Snr',
  },{
    name: 'Z',
  url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dry_Ohh.mp3',
  description: 'Dry_Ohh',
  },{
    name: 'X',
  url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3',
  description: 'Heater-3',
  },{
    name: 'C',
  url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3',
  description: 'Dsc_Oh',
  },
];

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      play:false,
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.audio);

    this.setState({
      play:!this.state.play,
    });

    this.audio.play();
    this.audio.currentTime = 0;
  }

  render(){
    let drumpad = keys.map(item => <div id={item.description}>
      <div id='display'>
        <button className='drum-pad' id={item.name} onClick={this.handleClick}>{item.name}
          <audio className='clip' id={item.name} src={item.url} ref={ref => this.audio = ref}/>
        </button>
      </div>
  </div>);

    return (
      <div id='drum-machine'>
        {drumpad}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite `this.audio` every single time as your `keys.map()` iterates through the array. I'd avoid using this.audio all together. Simply use the button onClick event. Pass event to the function, and use `console.log(event.target.querySelector('audio').play());`:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      play:false,
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({
      play:!this.state.play,
    });

    const audio = event.target.querySelector('audio');

    audio.play();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
  }

  render(){
    let drumpad = keys.map(item => <div id={item.description}>
      <div id='display'>
        <button className='drum-pad' id={item.name} onClick={this.handleClick}>{item.name}
          <audio className='clip' id={item.name} src={item.url} />
        </button>
      </div>
  </div>);

    return (
      <div id='drum-machine'>
        {drumpad}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks FrankerZ, it worked, one last question, how can I target the audio if the user pressed the letter associated with the sound?  I'm using the componentdidmount and componentwillunmount but i'm not sure how to target the correct sound within the function, any ideas?

Comment: Ah, that's a bit more difficult. You'll likely want to use ref again, but this time assign it like an object: `this.audio[item.name] = ref'`. In your componentDidMount, add the document event listeners, and when something get's pressed, call `this.audio[keyThatWasPressed]` to fetch the audio for that.